# Cross OS development in Tomcat. Can antiJARLocking and antiResourceLocking be set to True on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I have read that antiJARLocking and antiResourceLocking should be set to true if I'm running Tomcat on Windows.  These properties being set to true have resolved my deploy / undeploy issues on Windows.

My issue is that I have to develop locally on Windows, yet our test and prod servers are Linux.  My .war files have their own context.xml where I specify resource links, and the anti locking properties.  Can I safely keep these locking properties set to true when deploying on Linux?  I'd rather not have to change my context.xml when I deploy to the test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the meaning of *safe* for the test and production environments. Those settings on Linux should exhibit the same behaviour as on Windows (they may just be unnecessary on Linux). A test environment should be fine with those settings, as for production, well, that is harder to answer.

Those settings alter how the Tomcat class loader manages files (file handles). Performance appears to be the main concern [according to the antiResourceLocking Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html).

Given the potential performance penalty, I wouldn't think it would be worth keeping those settings in production unless they are really needed.